# Update Text in Combobox on Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, combobox, insert-update

I have a problem on update text in my Combo Box. I have the data on my combo box but if the data is not available, I want to type it by my self. How can I do that?

Comment: winform? asp.net? silverlight or wpf?

Comment: Did you try and got error ?

Comment: What have you tried? did it work or not? This site is not ment to give code if you haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

from Designer :

you need to goto `Items` Property of the `ComboBox` to Add the Items.

from Coding :

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item1");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item2");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item3");
```

Comment: Nope, i don't think you understood the question. "I want to type ..." in the question suggests that you don't add the items using code. It sounds to me that he is trying to imitate the behaviour of MS Access combo box